# Complex transfer functions squared

Tags: circuit-design, filter, transfer-function, band-pass

Why is it true that, for a Butterworth filter, we have \$|H_n(jw)|^{2} = H_n(jw)H_n(-jw) = \frac{1}{1+w^{2n}}\$?

I don't understand why the absolute value squared of this complex function has to be \$H_n(jw)H_n(-jw)\$.

And where does the gain \$|H(jw)| = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+(\frac{w}{w_c})^{2n}}}\$ come from? How is it derived? Is there an intuitive way of looking at it?

Comment: Although I'm also pretty loose with terms and don't claim any piety here, what you are staring at is better called the **magnitude**, not the **gain**. Vectors on the complex plain have **magnitude**. (Or **length**, but electronics people don't use **length**.) In the equation: $$H_s=A\cdot\frac{1}{s^2+1.414\:s+1}$$The 1st factor, \$A\$, is the **gain** and the 2nd factor (a Butterworth with \$f_{_0}\approx 159\:\text{mHz}\$) will have a **magnitude** that varies with frequency. It helps, sometimes, to avoid combining these two terms into a mush, unless the context demands it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Where does the gain
> \$|H(j\omega)|=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+\left(\dfrac{\omega}\omega_c\right)^{2n}}}\$
> come from. How is it derived?*

It's a mathematical definition of a low-pass filter that is maximally flat in the pass-band. If you think about it a little, it's impossible for the denominator to be less than 1 hence, \$|H(j\omega)|\$ cannot be more than one i.e. there are no resonant peaks in the spectrum. So, by definition this is a response of a maximally flat Butterworth filter.

But, if you want to consider a generalized 2nd order low-pass filter, I can drill-down through the algebra. A standard 2nd-order low pass filter can be written like this: -

$$H(s) = \dfrac{\omega_n^2}{s^2+ 2\zeta s\omega_n +\omega_n^2}$$

Converting the s-plane formula to the \$j\omega\$ axis we get: -

$$H(j\omega) = \dfrac{1}{1 - \dfrac{\omega^2}{\omega_n^2}+j2\zeta\dfrac{\omega}{\omega_n}}$$

<sub>I'm using "n" as a subscript (natural resonant frequency) but, it's the same as your "c" on this occasion. I'll use "N" later for stage-count. I don't like using the "c" subscript because it implies "cut-off frequency" and it isn't the same as "natural resonant frequency" except, when discussing Butterworth filters.</sub>

Taking the square root of the squared denominator terms reveals the magnitude: -

$$|H(j\omega)| = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\left(1 - \dfrac{\omega^2}{\omega_n^2}\right)^2+4\zeta^2\dfrac{\omega^2}{\omega_n^2}}}$$

And, if you drilled down a bit further you'd get this: -

$$|H(j\omega)| = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1 + \dfrac{\omega^2}{\omega_n^2}\cdot(4\zeta^2-2)+\dfrac{\omega^4}{\omega_n^4}}}$$

So, here's where we ask questions about the \$4\zeta^2 \$ part. Can you see that if \$4\zeta^2 \$ is less than 2, the denominator will become less than 1 thus, the whole function have a peak above unity. So, it's maximally flat when \$4\zeta^2 = 2\$ or \$\zeta = \frac{1}{\sqrt2}\$.

That's the Butterworth definition for a simple 2nd order low-pass filter: -

$$|H(j\omega)| = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1 +\dfrac{\omega^4}{\omega_n^4}}}$$

And, this can be generalized to \$N\$ stages: -

$$|H(j\omega)| = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1 +\left(\dfrac{\omega}{\omega_n}\right)^{2N}}}$$

Again, apologies if using "n" is confusing here. I know you have used "n" to indicate the number of 2nd order Butterworth stages but, I use "n" to indicate the "natural" resonant frequency of the filter.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an "intuitive way of looking" to your problem description.

The way of using the squared magnitude |H(jw|² has - more or less - historical reasons only.
However, it is not a "must".

The transfer function H(jw) is a complex function and, therefore, the magnitude of this function will have a denominator |D(jw)|=SQRT(Re²+Im²).

Hence, the square root will disappear for squaring the function |H(jw|- and then it is more easy to find and define some suitable polynominals (Butterworth, Chebyshev,..) for the denominator  which are (a) realizable and (b) can fulfill the users requirements.

The way of writing |H(jw|²=|H(jw)|*|H(-jw| has no important meaning. Such a form is just an indication for the fact that there will be a symmetric pole location in the upper (w>0) as well lower (w<0) imaginary part of the s-plan.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't understand why the absolute value squared of this complex function has to be \$H_n(jw)H_n(-jw)\$.

It comes from basic complex variables.
If a complex variable is:
$$z=x+jy$$
Then the complex conjugate of the variable is:
$$z^{*}=x-jy$$
The magnitude (absolute value) is:
$$|z|=\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}$$
We can see therefore that:
$$|z|^{2}=zz^{*}$$

In Laplace domain \$s=\sigma +j\omega \$. A function \$H(s)=H(\sigma,j\omega)\$, that is a ratio of polynomials with real coefficients, has  complex conjugate \$H(s)^{*}=H(s^{*})=H(\sigma,-j\omega)\$, so:
$$|H(s)|^{2}=H(s)H(s^{*})=H(\sigma,j\omega)H(\sigma,-j\omega)$$

Transform to the sinusoidal domain by setting \$\sigma=0\$ shows that:
$$|H(j\omega)|^{2}=H(j\omega)H(-j\omega)$$

===============================

Thanks to @Tesla23 for \$H(s)=H(\sigma,j\omega)\$, that is a ratio of polynomials with real coefficients, has  complex conjugate \$H(s)^{*}=H(s^{*})\$

Comment: You need to add that H(x) is a polynomial (or rational polynomial) with real coefficients, then this is good.  This enables you to say that \$H(s)^* = H(s^*)\$

Comment: Thanks @Tesla23: fixed